# How to resolve screen flickering in Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, intel-graphics, flicker

I have been using Xubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows XP. Today all of a sudden while surfing the Internet the screen started flickering. I restarted the computer, it ran successfully but the same issue came up. This time there where continuous beep sounds from the CPU. Please help.

Specs:

Intel Pentium D 3.00GHz
2GB RAM
Gigabyte G41-M Combo
Xubuntu 14.04 LTS & Windows XP

Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCUvU.jpg

Comment: Does it flicker in windows too or just Xubuntu

Comment: No XP is working well.

Comment: Please go to your display setting and make sure you have the correct refresh rate set (normaly 60hz or more). The most common cause of screen flicker is low refresh rate. Also do you have GPU drivers installed

Comment: If you use intigrated gpu (eg intel), go to Settings->Window manager tweaks and turn off compositing and tell me if this fixes it

Comment: Changed the refresh rate from 60 to 75hz. Working well for a while. Thank you Mark for your help & guidance

Comment: I will put this as an answer Please wait 12 hours or so to confirm the issue has been fully resolved, then please come by and accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to your display setting and make sure you have the correct refresh rate set (normaly 60hz or more). The most common cause of screen flicker is low refresh rate